# Unable to filter out

Tags: spotfire, tibco

i created a button with function "Filter out Marked rows" . It was working finely for last 2 months. Its not working now. does anyone knows reason. Its not working on any visuals or tables in  my report.

I tried to filter out by marking and right clicking. But the option is faded out. 
please see picture [image]

Comment: Strange... any permissions change?

Comment: Also, does this happen in the WP and Professional clients?

Comment: Yes happened with both

Comment: Hi scsimon,
i got answer for this, sorry for late . we need to check 'create automatically for all columns' in table properties for that particular table.

Comment: no worries. I learned something from your answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

check 'create automatically for all columns' in table properties for that particular table